# gracefully handling & in a param

Tags: javascript, urlsearchparams

consider

```js
> s = 'biome=Temparate Grasslands, Savannas & Shrublands&eco_region=grasslands'
'biome=Temparate Grasslands, Savannas & Shrublands&eco_region=grasslands'
> p = new URLSearchParams(s)
URLSearchParams {
  'biome' => 'Temparate Grasslands, Savannas ',
  ' Shrublands' => '',
  'eco_region' => 'grasslands' }
>
```

how do I get `URLSearchParams(s)` to do the following. I can't think of any other way short of detecting '&' and then doing the splitting myself, but that is not going to be easy as I have to distinguish between the first '&' and the second '&'. Suggestions?

```js
URLSearchParams {
  'biome' => 'Temparate Grasslands, Savannas & Shrublands',
  'eco_region' => 'grasslands' }
>
```

**context:** the string is coming from a web form filled by a non-technical user. They can enter a string, or they can enter a multi-param string. In other words, they can enter `Temparate Grasslands, Savannas & Shrublands` or `biome=Temparate Grasslands, Savannas & Shrublands&eco_region=grasslands`. In both cases, I want to do the right thing

I realize for long term I need to change the UI so users don't have to type in querystrings.

Comment: `&` is a special url char so URLSearchParams will split it. You should encode the `&` where you set it as url so it doesn't act like a queryParam.

Comment: You could however set the `size` to `1` so it will only parse `biome` but that will prevent `eco_region` from being parsed.

Comment: yes, I understand the specialness of `&` but can't figure out how to handle it. First, the string actually comes from user input in a form. I've tried `encodeURI(<form val>` but that doesn't help. Plus, I run into the same problem -- how to distinguish between the first `&` that is a part of the string, and the second `&` that separates two params

Comment: User input shouldn't be used as-is. As well, query string key/values should be url encoded. (You should not have `&` as part of a key or value, it should be `%26`. Similar for `=`, and space.)

Comment: The string you've shown as your starting point, `biome=Temparate Grasslands, Savannas & Shrublands&eco_region=grasslands`, is *already* messed up. It's not a valid URL query string. The place to fix this is wherever that string is being produced, because once it exists, it's already a problem.

Comment: *"the string is coming from a web form filled by a non-technical user"* Don't have non-technical users provide *query strings*; they don't know how. (Heck, it seems like 9 out of 10 web programmers don't even know how. :-) ) Instead, have them provide the names and values, and your code can then correctly URI-encode those names and values.

Comment: "the string actually comes from user input in a form" then you should be URI encoding it, period. "how to distinguish between the first & that is a part of the string, and the second & that separates two params" you don't, because you don't let users type query strings directly because then you can't sanitize the input.

Comment: That well may be my only option but it will require a major update to the user-facing application which will take time. I am hoping for a solution that can avoid that, but failing which…

Comment: @punkish yeah that sucks we've all been there. Run it past your infosec folks, because they almost certainly won't be happy with the existing state of affairs and you can say "hey infosec wants me to change this because it's a security hole". But realistically you are going to have to write a complicated (read: fragile) ad hoc parser and do it all by hand which is also a security risk plus complicated tech debt...or bite the bullet and do it the right way.

Comment: @punkish - As Jared said, ugh, we've been there. There's no general solution if your starting point is a "query string" where some of the `&` are, correctly, delimiters and other `&` are, incorrectly, not delimiters. You may be able to apply some domain-specific knowledge to fix it (in your example, for instance, there are spaces on either side of the `&` which makes it likely that it's not a delimiter), but that's always going to be imperfect.

Comment: @JaredSmith - Oooh I love that. Clever tactic.

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted out @punkish, but instead od copying our answer to your question it's better to upvote/accept any of the answers that helped.

Comment: your answer was not wrong @0stone0 and it deserved and got my upvote. It was a fragile solution to an even more fragile situation which needs to be changed, but will take a long time. In the meantime, I have to implement a solution that works mostly. Re. URI encoding user input, yes, I am already doing that. Re. not having users type querystrings -- yes, that would be ideal, but they have come to expect to do that. Never had `&` till now, so it worked. Now I have to look ahead to a more permanent solution. Thanks again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the `&`'s that needs to be ignored, you can `replaceAll`  `&`  with the encoded `%26` before passing to `URLSearchParams`

```js
r = / & /g;

s = 'biome=Temparate Grasslands, Savannas & Shrublands&eco_region=grasslands';

s = s.replaceAll(r, '%20%26%20');

for (const p of new URLSearchParams(s)) {
    console.log(p);
}
```

---

However, it's better to fix this at the source so that any queryParamater value uses encoded values.

Comment: you solution was very helpful (along with mplungian's suggestion). I upvoted your suggestion. Thank you

Comment: Did not downvote but this is fragile...

Comment: `tabletop=D&D` or `provider=AT&T` would not work with this.  Extremely fragile and only really applicable to this data. Since it's user submitted they might even mistype it and have something like `Savannas& Shrublands` omitting a space.

Comment: all valid points, which is why I need to rewrite a real solution, but that will take time